# Image being rotated when user picks one from photo gallery

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently making an app where one of the views allows the user to take a pic of their schedule from their photo library and it would be saved in the app. The saving feature works fine. However, when the user selects an image, it is rotated 90 degrees. For example, a portrait picture would be rotated and resized which makes it hard to read. How can I disable the rotating feature?

```
import UIKit

class Schedule: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // User picks image
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage

            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "image")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // User cancels picking image action
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self

        if let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image") as? NSData {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common behaviour, you can see that even in apps like Whatsapp and others.

The reason why you see it right in the Photos app is because they use the information of the sensors to determine what's the correct orientation.

You can prove this by copying the photos from iPhone to a Windows PC, you will see not all the photos are in the correct orientation.

I'm not sure if you can access those metadata to determine it yourself.

At least Whatsapp uses a button to rotate the images as requested by the user, that could be a temporary solution.